# Form validation not updationg when values are updated. but errors on load correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

i have added a form validation. when there is no value in fields it works fine on submit. in case if i added valid data to the form field on submit the errors not clearing. not able to understand the issue.

here is my code :

```
const App = () => {
  const { values, onChangeHandler, onSubmitForm, errors } =
    FormValidator(ValueValidator);

  console.log('errors', errors);
  return (
    <div>
      <form
        name="contactform"
        className="contactform"
        autoComplete="off"
        onSubmit={onSubmitForm}
      >
        <label htmlFor="username" className={errors.username ? 'error' : ''}>
          <input
            id="username"
            name="username"
            autoComplete="off"
            onChange={onChangeHandler}
            value={values.username}
            placeholder="Name"
            type="text"
          />
        </label>
        <p>{errors.username && 'user name is required'}</p>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email" className={errors.email ? 'error' : ''}>
            <input
              placeholder="Email"
              autoComplete="off"
              onChange={onChangeHandler}
              value={values.email}
              type="email"
              name="email"
              id="email"
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <label className="message" htmlFor="message">
          <textarea
            placeholder="Message"
            autoComplete="off"
            name="message"
            id="message"
          ></textarea>
        </label>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5vwfns?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because your not actually resetting

```
let errors = initialErrorsProps;
```

In valueValidator.tsx like you think you are.

When you do

```
errors.email = 'Email name required';
```

You're actually updating is the reference to the initialErrorsProps const. So you'll see when you resubmit after failed validation, errors is already filled with the previous values.

This occurs because objects are passed by reference. More details are here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/7528450

A simple solution would be just to set your object at the beginning of the method:

```
let errors = {
   username: '',
   email: '',
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. i used the spread operator `let errors = {...initialErrorsProps}` works fine.

Comment: Ah, that's a cleaner way of doing it. Good job.